# jQuery autocomplete and aspx / json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I am fairly new to jQuery and JSON and have run into a problem I haven't been able to solve.  I have a textbox that I would like a user to start typing a person's name and when he/she selects the name, it autopopulates another textbox with their email address.

My code is as follows.  Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much in advance!

Markup

```
<input type="text" id="person_name" class="required" />
<input type="text" id="person_email_address" class="required email" />
```

jQuery

```
$( "input#person_name" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/autoComplete.aspx",
    dataType: "json",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        //set email textbox to the email field of the selected item.
    }
});
```

autoComplete.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string term = Request.QueryString["term"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
    {
        string sql = string.Format("select * from users where first_name like '%{0}%' or last_name like '%{0}%'", term);

        DataTable dt = GetTable(sql);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string name = dr["first_name"].ToString() + dr["last_name"].ToString();
            string email = dr["email"].ToString();
        }

        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Response.Write("what goes here so i can access both email and name in the select function?");
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick tips on the code: consider using a parameterised query instead to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities, and try using a WebMethod on a page or Web Service to return the data as an array of strongly typed objects with `name`, `email`, and `value` properties, which .NET will automatically convert to JSON for you.

Comment: Is that as simple as slapping a [WebMethod] attribute on top of a new method?  How would I call it from the jQuery?

Comment: See this fantastic page by Dave Ward with links to all his super helpful ASP.NET meets jQuery blog posts - I learnt most of what I know about it from him: http://encosia.com/jquery-for-the-asp-net-developer/

Comment: Good stuff there...thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this in your code-behind:

```
var items = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(
    dr => new 
    {
        name = dr["first_name"].ToString() + dr["last_name"].ToString(),
        email = dr["email"].ToString()
    }
);
string json = "[" + string.Join(",", 
        items.Select(i => 
            "{ id: '" + i.name + "'"
            + ", label: '" + i.name + "'"
            + ", value: '" + i.email + "'"
            + "}"
        )
    ) + "]";

Response.Write(json);
```

That should get you the correct JSON, with *name* as the label, and *email* as the value.  Now in the Javascript select callback function, set the email textbox to the correct value:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    //set email textbox to the email field of the selected item.
    $("#person_email_address") = ui.item.value;
}
```

**NOTE**

*Per comments, the above is invalid without modification.  The JSON values have to be wrapped in double quotes.*

Comment: This actually helps out tremendously.  I'm actually working with 2.0 so I don't have linq unfortunately :( Should the label/value string looks something like [{id: 'name1', label: 'name1', value: 'email1'},{id: 'name2', label: 'name2', value: 'email2'}]?

Comment: @user1174729 Yes, exactly. Ouch on not having Linq.  I guess you would have to construct the JSON inside the loop, then?

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one, I ultimately got it working...i had some formatting issues with JSON.  I had to wrap my label and values with double ticks (") instead of single ticks (')

Comment: @user1174729 cool ... I updated my answer in case anyone else comes across this.  I actually wondered if the single quotes would be invalid, but thought to myself "nah, JQuery is smart enough to handle that".